# Solve the equation $\frac{x-13}{x-14}-\frac{x-15}{x-16}=-\frac{1}{12}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the equation $$\dfrac{x-13}{x-14}-\dfrac{x-15}{x-16}=-\dfrac{1}{12}.$$
For $x\ne14$ and $x\ne 16$ by multiplying the whole equation by $$12(x-14)(x-16)$$ we get: $$12(x-16)(x-13)-12(x-14)(x-15)=-(x-14)(x-16).$$ This doesn't look very nice. Can we do something else at the beginning? $$x-14=(x-13)-1\\x-15=(x-14)-1\\..?$$

Comment: Simplify the equation maybe?

Comment: @OscarLanzi, the equation that I got after multiplying or the original problem?

Comment: I mean, the equation you got is just a quadratic equation, so if you expand everything out and simplify you will be fine.

Comment: $(x-16)(x-13)=(x-14.5-1.5)(x-14.5+1.5)=(x-14.5)^2-1.5^2$ and $(x-14)(x-15)=(x-14.5+0.5)(x-14.5-0.5)=(x-14.5)^2-0.5^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that

$$\frac{x-13}{x-14} = \frac{x-14+1}{x-14} = 1 + \frac{1}{x-14} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

$$\frac{x-15}{x-16} = \frac{x-16+1}{x-16} = 1 + \frac{1}{x-16} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Comment: Thank you for the response! But is actually $$24(x-14)(x-16)+12(x-16)+12(x-14)=-(x-14)(x-16)$$ actually easier to work with than $$12(x-16)(x-13)-12(x-14)(x-15)=-(x-14)(x-16)...$$ Hardly.

Comment: You're welcome. However, note since the $2$ fractions are *subtracted* from each other, the $1$ terms disappear (i.e., don't become $2$ as you're stating in your comment). Thus, with my suggestion, you get $\frac{1}{x-14} - \frac{1}{x-16} = -\frac{1}{12}$ which becomes $12(x-16) - 12(x-14) = -(x-14)(x-16) \implies -48 = -x^2 + 30 - 224$ which, to me at least, is a bit easier to deal with than your original equation of $12(x-16)(x-13)-12(x-14)(x-15)=-(x-14)(x-16)$.

Comment: @Medi You're welcome. Note I have a small mistake in my comment. The $-48$ on the left side of the expansion should be $-24$ instead. Thus, the equation becomes $-24 = -x^2 + 30 - 224 \implies x^2 - 30 + 200 = 0 \implies (x-20)(x-10) = 0$, as stated in J.G.'s answer.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{x-13}{x-14} - \frac{x-15}{x-16} = -\frac{1}{12}$$

Let $x = t+ 15$

\begin{align}
   \frac{t+2}{t+1} - \frac{t}{t-1} &= -\frac{1}{12} \\
   \dfrac{(t^2+t-2) - (t^2+t)}{t^2-1} &= -\frac{1}{12} \\
   \dfrac{-2}{t^2-1} &= -\frac{1}{12} \\
   t^2-1 &= 24 \\
   t^2 &= 25 \\
   t &= \pm 5 \\
   x &= 20, 10
\end{align}

Comment: Your answer is the only one which uses the substitution you mention and truly makes the question very easy to manipulate. +1, keep going , we need more from you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Notice that if we visually erase the symbols "$x - 1$" in both numerators and denominators we are left with $\frac34$ and $\frac56$ respectively, which is nice because

$$
\frac34 = \frac{9}{12}\quad\text{and}\quad\frac56 = \frac{10}{12}.
$$

Comment: Hint: Notice that the answer is $x=16$ :)

Answer (score 1):

It's easier if you subtract $1$ from each term on the LHS, i.e. $$-\frac{1}{12}=\frac{1}{x-14}-\frac{1}{x-16}=\frac{-2}{(x-14)(x-16)},$$ which is equivalent to $$(x-14)(x-16)=24.$$ This can be rearranged to $(x-10)(x-20)=0$.

Comment: How did you get $$-\dfrac{1}{12}=\dfrac{1}{x-14}-\dfrac{1}{x-16}=\dfrac{-2}{(x-14)(x-16)}?$$

Comment: No, I meant from the original problem. I didn't understand the part where we are substactring 1 from each term on the LHS. Why can we do that?

Comment: @Medi Because $(a+1)-(b+1)=a-b$.

Comment: So as far as I can see it's better not to multiply the whole equation $$\dfrac{1}{x-14}-\dfrac{1}{x-16}=-\dfrac{1}{12}$$ because it's easier (the calculations) to just work on the LHS?

Comment: @Medi It's a nice aspect of this particular problem. Multiplying out, you end up with a constant on the LHS, whereas a more general problem would give a quadratic.

Comment: Thank you! But how can I note this in other problems? I mean whether to multiply the whole equation or work on the LHS with the fractions.

Comment: @Medi $\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}-\frac{ex+f}{gx+h}$ admits this treatment if $a/e=c/g$ and $c,\,g\ne0$.

Comment: I am not sure I understood your last comment. I meant in the given problem it is easier to do the following thing $$\dfrac{1}{x-14}-\dfrac{1}{x-16}=-\dfrac{1}{12}\\ \iff \dfrac{-2}{(x-14)(x-16)}=-\dfrac{1}{12}\\ \iff (x-14)(x-16)=24,$$ than multuplying the whole equation by $12(x-14)(x-16)$ to get $$12(x-16)-12(x-14)=-(x-14)(x-16),$$ right? My question is - as far as I know this isn't always true, so what are the things that we can note in the particular equation to use it to reduce our work?

Comment: Also may I ask you if I can use the sign of equivalence ($\iff$) here. Are the equations $$\dfrac{1}{x-14}-\dfrac{1}{x-16}=-\dfrac{1}{12}$$ and $$(x-10)(x-20)=0$$ equivalent? They don't have the same domains at first.

Comment: @Medi Well, $\frac{1}{x-14}-\frac{1}{x-16}=-\frac{1}{12}$ iff $x-14\ne0$ and $x-16\ne0$ and $-24=(x-14)(x-16)$, so the domains of the functions aren't a problem.